# Looking for a Small Used/New End User Android phone with Minimal Bloatware under $200

Tags: android, smartphones

Good afternoon,

I'm looking to buy an older flagship touchscreen model smartphone, as my primary phone, and I would like to know your opinions and recommendations on what I should look for. My price range is $100-$200

I'm looking for something with a small footprint, like around a 4" screen.

My carrier is T-Mobile, so any unlocked GSM smartphone is okay

No or little bloatware. This is important to me. This is why I can't buy samsung phones anymore.

Performance and features comparable to a galaxy s5. Longer battery life preferable. I dont play any games on it, but do need reliable and glitch free smooth performance.

Custom firmware should be available for this phone, and tools for flashing it should be available as well.

Galaxy S5 Mini was a perfect option for me, until I found that I wasn't able to load custom firmware on it, and it was constantly running updates on processes I was not able to get rid of.

I heard good things about Motorola phones and their platform of little to no bloatware. Is this true? Are they comparable in quality?

Any suggestions for specific models of phones would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I've approved your edit, but in future you should sign in to your account to edit your question, as then it doesn't have to go through the review process. I've also removed your question about used phones and spyware since that isn't on-topic here, but the recommendation you're asking for is.

Comment: Did you actually ever go ahead and buy a phone? Or are you still looking for a recommendation?